# @react-native-picker/picker causes my app to crash (android)

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to use react-native-picker-select package. and @react-native-picker/picker is a dependency according to their docs. but..

After adding this package to my RN app, it builds without error but the app crashes.

Looked for issues on their repo, but i dont think there are resources for the fix. Already created an issue also on their repo.

Comment: Hello, you should post the error message to see what is happening.

Comment: Hi, there is no error being shown. The app crashes after the build.

Comment: So run the application with Android Studio open, in the logcat you should see the error. You probably won't see anything due to it being a Java bug rather than a JS bug.

Comment: On a weird tangent, android crashed with this error. I searched my project and discovered `react-native-picker` wasn't even being used. Must've been a dev holdover. I removed the library, rebuilt android and POOF error was gone. So that's one thing to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of figuring out, instead of using @react-native-picker/picker... use @react-native-community/picker instead even tho they said it's already deprecated.

I've finally successfully run my app while using react-native-picker-select and @react-native-community/picker.

Comment: As of upgrading to Expo 35 @react-native-community/picker is deprecated and will crash your build, while @react-native-picker/picker will perform as expected.  When building locally both seem to perform equally, leading to some tough debugging...

Answer (score 5):

Add a `<Text></Text>` component after the `<Picker></Picker>` component, inside the parent `<View></View>` component of the `<Picker></Picker>` component, just like in the code snippet below:

```
        <View style={{flex: 1, borderWidth: 1, borderColor: '#0f0'}}>
          <Picker
            style={{...styles.itemPicker, color: theme.TEXT}}
            mode="dropdown"
            selectedValue={unit_elevation}
            onValueChange={(value) => this.changeUserPreferences('unit_elevation', value)}
          >
            <Picker.Item label={messages.meters} value="M" />
            <Picker.Item label={messages.feet} value="FT" />
          </Picker>
          <Text style={{width: '100%', height: 60, position: 'absolute', bottom: 0, left: 0}}>{' '}</Text>
        </View>
```

Comment: no way ! :) how did you even figure this out? thank you 

Comment: @ayobamijohn does this actually solve the issue for you?  In my environment, adding the Text component prevents the crash, but does not fix the issue of the Picker failing

Comment: @ShepSims yes it solves it. I was really surpised. Sorry I'm just replying

Answer (score 2):

For me, the issue was caused because I was passing a label integer value in `Picker.Item` component.
By passing a string value, the issue was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

From my testing it seems like if you're running on Expo 34 or previous, you are not required to provide the extra dependency in most cases, but the @react-native-community/picker package works as well.

If you have upgraded to Expo SDK 35 or beyond however, the additional dependency **is required** and only @react-native-picker/picker will work correctly and not crash.

Comment: I'm not using Expo tho, I'm using react native cli for this project that I had issue with this component.